# How to define a method in Scala that returns a Java object?

Tags: scala

I want to define a private method in scala singleton class that looks like;

```
private def  createDomNode(tag: String, attrs: Map[String , String]): DomNode  {

}
```

DomNode is Java type, not scala type. attrs is scala Map with both key and value being of type String.

But above gives error. What is the correct format?

Thanks Easy Angel for the answer. There is still some confusion. According to Programming in Scala book written by the inventor of the language, the below is a function:

```
def max(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
  if (x > y) x
  else y
}
```

But your answer says it is method and not function. Can you kindly explain?

What is REPL?

Comment: REPL means 'read-eval-print loop', an interactive shell. You can start the Scala REPL by running the `scala` command line program.

Comment: This might help with the method vs. function confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926047/debunking-scala-myths/4812176#4812176.

Comment: Don't mix questions together, which are only randomly connected (REPL, function/method, first question).

Comment: Please stop adding more questions to this one.  If an answer leads you to a new question, feel free to ask a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: @ace Instead of leaving replies to answers in the question itself, you should post a comment with `@` followed by the username you are replying to. That will notify the user of the message you are writing to them.

Answer (score 48):

You should just put `=`:

```
private def createDomNode(tag: String, attrs: Map[String , String]): DomNode = {
    // ...
}
```

If you will not put `=` between method signature and body, then return type is `Unit`, so this:

```
def m(i: Int) {}
```

is the same as

```
def m(i: Int): Unit = {}
```

---

*Response to the comment*: What I described earlier is actually method, if you define it within `object`, `class` or `trait` definition. Function syntax would look like this:

```
val createDomNode: (String, Map[String , String]) => DomNode = { (tag, attrs) =>
    // ...
}
```

As You can see I define `val` with name `createDomNode` of function type. It can also be written like:

```
val createDomNode: Function2[String, Map[String , String], DomNode] = { (tag, attrs) =>
    // ...
}
```

here is another example. In this case I define method that generates new function each time you call it:

```
def createDomNode = (tag: String, attrs: Map[String , String]) => new DomNode
```

But it's important to understand, that method returns a "function that returns `DomNode`"  in this case, but not `DomNode` itself.

---

*About Programming in Scala reference*. I think you are talking about **Chapter 2 - Step 3 (in the intro)**

As you can see `max` function is defined in REPL, and it's really function. Actually you can also write something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    def myMethod(i: Int): Int = {
        def myInnerFn(x: Int) = x * x

        myInnerFn(i)
    }
}
```

In this case `myMethod` is method and `myInnerFn` is function. So as you can see, it highly depends on the context. I believe this syntax for `myInnerFn` is just syntactic sugar for (I need to look in spec in order to say for sure):

```
val myInnerFn = (x: Int) => x * x
```

The same happens in REPL. And by the way that's because I wrote at the beginning:

> if you define it within `object`, `class` or `trait` definition

Sorry, I need to be more clear about this and describe it in more detail in my second update.

---

I looked in Scala spec. Seems that I'm not totally correct when I say that `myInnerFn` is syntactic sugar for the function. but seems that it's called **Method Type**. You can find it in spec section **3.3.1 Method Type**:

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

hope it will give you some clue, if you want to dive deeper in this. I think it's easy to get lost in terminology. You can `function` in 2 contexts. In first we have

- Function - returns some value
- Procedure - returns no value (or in Scala context it returns `Unit`)

And in second context:

- Function - executable piece of code that can be passes around and treated as value
- Method - belongs to the class

And it's sometimes not clear in what context it meant. For example I can tell you that `myMethod` is as function just because it has return value (or in other words: *`myMethod` it's not procedure*). I believe it's the same case in book.

---

One more thing. Sections 8.1, 8.2, 8.3 from *Programming in Scala* can help you to understand this terminology. And if I'm correct in my assumptions, what you think as `Function` is called `First-class function` in the book (it's described in section 8.3).

Hope this helps

Comment: But putting an equal will change it into a scala function and not scala method.

Comment: I want method and not function.

Comment: @amc: Adding the equals sign *does not* change it into a scala function. If you do the whole `val createDomNode = ( ... ) =>` thing, then you get a function.

Comment: The equal sign just states that the method is returning something (i. e. something other than Unit). See this Question/Answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration

Comment: Yes that is correct that example is Chapter 2 step 3 page 72.