# When do I have to treat my methods as partially applied functions in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, partial-application

I noticed that when I'm working with functions that expect other functions as parameters, I can sometimes do this:

```
someFunction(firstParam,anotherFunction)
```

But other times, the compiler is giving me an error, telling me that I should write a function like this, in order for it to treat it as a partially applied function:

```
someFunction(firstParam,anotherFunction _)
```

For example, if I have this:

```
object Whatever {
    def meth1(params:Array[Int]) = ...
    def meth2(params:Array[Int]) = ...
}

import Whatever._
val callbacks = Array(meth1 _,meth2 _)
```

Why can't I have the code like the following:

```
val callbacks = Array(meth1,meth2)
```

Under what circumstances will the compiler tell me to add `_`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The rule is actually simple: you have to write the `_` whenever the compiler is not explicitly expecting a `Function` object.

Example in the REPL:

```
scala> def f(i: Int) = i    
f: (i: Int)Int

scala> val g = f
<console>:6: error: missing arguments for method f in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       val g = f
               ^

scala> val g: Int => Int = f  
g: (Int) => Int = <function1>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Scala a method **is not** a function. The compiler can convert a method implicitly in a function, but it need to know which kind. So either you use the `_` to convert it explicitly or you can give some indications about which function type to use:

```
object Whatever {
  def meth1(params:Array[Int]): Int = ...
  def meth2(params:Array[Int]): Int = ...
}

import Whatever._
val callbacks = Array[ Array[Int] => Int ]( meth1, meth2 )
```

or:

```
val callbacks: Array[ Array[Int] => Int ] = Array( meth1, meth2 )
```

Comment: See also [Myth: methods and functions are the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926047/debunking-scala-myths/4812176#4812176).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Jean-Philippe Pellet said, you can use partially applied functions, when writing delegate classes:

```
class ThirdPartyAPI{
   def f(a: Int, b: String, c: Int) = ...
   // lots of other methods
}

// You want to hide all the unnecessary methods
class APIWrapper(r: ThirdPartyAPI) {
   // instead of writing this
   def f(a: Int, b: String, c: Int) = r.f(a, b, c)
   // you can write this
   def f(a: Int, b: String, c: Int) = r.f _
   // or even this
   def f = r.f _
}
```

**EDIT** added the `def f = r.f _` part.

Comment: Note that it's not a *partial function*, it's a *partially applied function*.

Comment: Shouldn't (r: RichAPI) be (r: ThnirdPartyAPI)?

Comment: shouldn't the "//you can write this part" be: def f = r.f _ ?
that creates f: (a: Int,b: String,c: Int)(Int, String, Int) => ...

Comment: I thought it's only possible with a function, but not a method. Nice to know, thx. I'll add it right away

Comment: @JaimeJorge @agilesteel the case `def f = r.f _` is different. `f` now becomes a method without a parameter list which returns a function of type `(Int, String, Int) => A`. There is some overhead here.

Comment: @jean-philippe-pellet true, thanks. but the interface for the client is the same (and also reduces the number of keystrokes required).

Comment: The interface is not exactly the same — e.g., the client cannot use named parameters any more (or not the ones you'd think).