# Eta-expansion between methods and functions with overloaded methods in Scala

Tags: function, scala, methods, implicit-conversion

I would like to understand why the eta-expansion (§6.26.5) does not work for overloaded methods. For example, if I have following two methods:

```
def d1(a: Int, b: Int) {}
def r[A, B](delegate: (A, B) ⇒ Unit) {}
```

I can do this:

```
r(d1)
```

But, when overloading `r` it will no longer work:

```
def r[A, B](delegate: (A, B) ⇒ Unit) {}
def r[A, B, C](delegate: (A, B, C) ⇒ Unit) {}

r(d1) // no longer compiles
```

and I have to explicitly convert method into partially applied function:

```
r(d1 _)
```

Is there any way to accomplish following with the explicit conversion?

```
def r[A, B](delegate: (A, B) ⇒ Unit) {}
def r[A, B, C](delegate: (A, B, C) ⇒ Unit) {}

def d1(a: Int, b: Int) {}
def d2(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) {}

r(d1) // only compiles with r(d1 _)
r(d2) // only compiles with r(d2 _)
```

There is somewhat similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650989/when-do-i-have-to-treat-my-methods-as-partially-applied-functions-in-scala), but it is not fully explained.

Comment: Interesting! By the way, I don't think "implicit conversion" is the right term to use here (at least for Scala), as there is no `implicit def` involved.

Comment: I think it's called *implicit η-conversion*.

Comment: I think @gzm0 is right, I changed it to "Automatically"

Comment: It is called the eta-expansion (§6.26.5) - updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Note that you can do `r[Int, Int](d1)`, although that's more verbose than `r(d1 _)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implicit is the correct term, and the section is 6.26.2 in the spec, and this must be a duplicate question (or so one would think; this is stable behavior).

The linked question also answers that the expected type must be a function.

I'll go out on a limb and say that when overloaded, applicability is undermined because there is no expected type (6.26.3, infamously). When not overloaded, 6.26.2 applies (eta expansion) because the type of the parameter determines the expected type.  When overloaded, the arg is specifically typed with no expected type, hence 6.26.2 doesn't apply; therefore neither overloaded variant of `d` is deemed to be applicable.

> From 6.26.3 Overloading Resolution
>
> Otherwise, let S 1 , . . . , S m be the vector of types obtained by
>   typing each argument with an undefined expected type.

Here are the "implicit conversions" (so-called) available when you name a method without args, as in `r(d1)`.  The paragraph on eta expansion applies here.

> 6.26.2 Method Conversions
>
> The following four implicit conversions can be applied to methods
>   which are not applied to some argument list.
>
> Evaluation. A parameterless method m of type => T is always converted
>   to type T by evaluating the expression to which m is bound.
>
> Implicit Application. If the method takes only implicit parameters,
>   implicit argu- ments are passed following the rules of §7.2.
>
> Eta Expansion. Otherwise, if the method is not a constructor, and the
>   expected type pt is a function type (Ts ) ⇒ T , eta-expansion
>   (§6.26.5) is performed on the expression e.
>
> Empty Application. Otherwise, if e has method type ()T , it is
>   implicitly applied to the empty argument list, yielding e()

More post-green-check explanation...

The following example demonstrates preferring application to eta-expansion in the presence of overloading.  When eta-expansion doesn't apply, "empty application" is the final implicit to try in 6.26.2.  In other words, when overloading (which is confusing and evil enough on the face of it), it is natural to take `f` as `f()` by the uniform access principle, but it is unnatural or weird to take `f` as `f _` unless you're quite sure a function type is expected.

```
scala> object Bar {
     | def r(f: () => Int) = 1
     | def r(i: Int) = 2
     | }
defined module Bar

scala> def f() = 4
f: ()Int

scala> Bar.r(f)
res4: Int = 2

scala> Bar.r(f _)
res5: Int = 1
```

Candidates for overloading resolution are pre-screened by "shape".  The shape test encapsulates the intuition that eta-expansion is never used because args are typed without an expected type. This example shows that eta-expansion is not used even when it is "the only way for the expression to type check."

```
scala> object Bar {
     | def bar(f: () => Int) = 1
     | def bar(is: Array[Int]) = 2
     | }
defined object Bar

scala> def m() = 7
m: ()Int

scala> m _
res0: () => Int = <function0>

scala> Bar.bar(m)
<console>:10: error: overloaded method value bar with alternatives:
  (is: Array[Int])Int <and>
  (f: () => Int)Int
 cannot be applied to (Int)
              Bar.bar(m)
                  ^
```

Anyone reading this far will be curious about [a related issue with these two conversions](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7187).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the relevant sections from the spec (it is the 6.23.3 and 6.26.5 that applies here). I don't think it is duplicate question (or at least I did not find any). It is clear that the expected type must be a function, but I was wondering why the eta-conversion cannot be applied while the expected type of the expression (`delegate`) is a function type (§6.25.2) - well apparently not from the eta-perspective point of view.

Comment: I haven't tried it with fancy compiler options set, but the issue is not eta-expansion point of view, but overload resolution point of view. You asked for `r` so your `d1` is typed with no expected type during overload resolution, which means no eta expansion (no automatic d1 _).

Comment: I think this is it, I misunderstood the overload resolution. How about to delete the citation from 6.26.2 from your answer as it is irrelevant.

Comment: That's where the rule about "must be expected function type" is defined.  I'll edit my parenthesis to clarify.

Comment: OK, I just think it is too verbose (too long citation), perhaps a citation from the overload resolution would be more beneficial?

Comment: So, when people upvote and favorite a question but not an answer, does that mean, "Hey, that's a really interesting question! though I don't really care to know what the answer is."  Sometimes it happens the other way, when people upvote an answer as useful without rewarding the question for eliciting it.

Comment: Great job - now the answer is much better!

Comment: Lots of great info here.  Still, I'm missing something in the end.  Just a bit more discussion to map the spec'd behavior to why, exactly, the first example works, but not the second?  Maybe I need to go read 6.25.2...