# Why are Scala class methods not first-class citizens?

Tags: function, scala, methods

I've just started Scala and am tinkering in worksheets. For example:

```
def merp(str: String) : String = s"Merrrrrrrp $str"
val merp2 = (str: String) => s"Merrrrrrrp $str"
val merp3 = (str: String) => merp(str)
val merp4 = merp _
merp("rjkghleghe")
merp4("rjkghleghe")
```

And the corresponding worksheet results:

```
merp: merp[](val str: String) => String
merp2: String => String = <function1>
merp3: String => String = <function1>
merp4: String => String = <function1>
res0: String = Merrrrrrrp rjkghleghe
res1: String = Merrrrrrrp rjkghleghe
```

Saying, for example, `val merp5 = merp` produces an error, because apparently methods cannot be values the way functions can. But I can still pass methods as arguments. I demonstrate this in the following code snippet, adapted from [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala):

```
def intCombiner(a: Int, b: Int) : String = s"herrrrrrp $a derrrrrrp $b"
def etaAbstractor[A, B](combineFoo: (A, B) ⇒ String, a: A, b: B) = combineFoo(a, b)
etaAbstractor(intCombiner, 15, 16)
```

worksheet result:

```
intCombiner: intCombiner[](val a: Int,val b: Int) => String
etaAbstractor: etaAbstractor[A,B](val combineFoo: (A, B) => String,val a: A,val b: B) => String
res10: String = herrrrrrp 15 derrrrrrp 16
```

---

1. Is methods-not-being-first-class a limitation, perhaps imposed by Scala's JVM interaction, or is it a decision in the language's design?
2. Why do I need to roll my own [eta abstractions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion), as in `merp3`?
3. Is `merp4` also an [eta abstraction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion), or is it something sneakily similar?
4. Why does my `etaAbstractor` work? Is Scala quietly replacing `intCombiner` with `intCombiner _`?

Theoretical, computer sciencey answers are welcome, as are pointers to any relevant points in the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/). Thanks!

Comment: The design and implementation of Scala *is* closely coupled to Java/JVM compatibility in many areas - I'm fairly certain it would be a thinner difference without such, but you'd have to ask Martin (I think he visits SO on occasion) or find some earlier impl notes. Although they can be easily 'promoted' with `method _`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a computer scientist, but I will try to guess:

1. Method is a part of an object and doesn't exist outside of it. You can't pass method alone. Closure is another (equivalent?) way of encapsulating state, by converting an object method to a standalone function (which is by the way just another object with `apply()` method in Scala) you are creating a closure. This process is known as eta-expansion. [§3.3.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#method-types), [§6.26.5](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion)
2. You don't have to. You can also write `val merp3 : (String => String) = merp`. [§6.26.5](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion)
3. Yes, `merp4` is eta-expansion too. [§6.7](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values)
4. [§6.26.2](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-conversions)

Comment: Python and JavaScript have methods that *are* first-class functions so #1 is "In Scala (and Java) ..".

Comment: @user2864740 In Python unbound method can't be called, so it doesn't look to me as a first-class function. Assigning a bound method looks like eta-expansion under the hood. Javascript has the same problem if you use `this` inside your function, only instead of error you will have `undefined` as a value of `this`.

Comment: It still remains that methods are *not* first-class values but are rather 'manifestations of definitions' that are invoked-by-name (or [message passing OO](http://www.desy.de/gna/html/cc/Tutorial/node5.htm#SECTION00540000000000000000)). Maintaining a context (or not) doesn't affect their citizenship status: or the fundamental implementation differences.

Comment: Many thanks for the links to specs. To complete Q#1, I speculate that it is a language design decision resulting from how the Scala code gets translated into the JVM. Specifically, a method (being an abstraction with no value) can be finalized on compilation, while a `Function` -- being an object, and its attendant closure being a dynamic tree structure -- can only be created at runtime. To make the method concrete, a `Function` object must be created. This can have performance consequences, so it'd be a good decision to require that programmers explicitly create that object and not mislead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works with `etaAbstractor` is that the compiler can infer that a function (not a function invocation) is required.

If I had to guess *why* the underscore is required where a function type cannot be inferred, I'd think that it's to improve error reporting of a common class of errors (getting functions where invocations are intended).  But again, that's just a guess.

In the JVM, a method is not an object, whereas a first-class function must be one.  So the method must be boxed into an object to convert it to a function.