# Dataset filter: eta expansion is not done automatically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have a simple Scala collection of Ints and I define a simple **method** `isPositive` to return true if the value is greater than 0, then I can just pass the method to the `filter` method of the collection, like in the example below

```
def isPositive(i: Int): Boolean = i > 0

val aList = List(-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3)
val newList = aList.filter(isPositive)

> newList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

So as far as I understand, the compiler is able to automatically convert the method into a function instance by doing eta expansion, and then it passes this function as parameter.

However, if I do the same thing with a Spark Dataset:

```
val aDataset = aList.toDS
val newDataset = aDataset.filter(isPositive)

> error
```

It fails with the well-known "missing arguments for method" error. To make it work, I have to explicitly convert the method into a function by using "_":

```
val newDataset = aDataset.filter(isPositive _)

> newDataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]
```

Although with `map` it works as expected:

```
val newDataset = aDataset.map(isPositive)

> newDataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Boolean] = [value: boolean]
```

Investigating the signatures, I see that the signature for Dataset's filter is very similar to List's filter:

```
// Dataset:
def filter(func: T => Boolean): Dataset[T]

// List (Defined in TraversableLike):
def filter(p: A => Boolean): Repr
```

So, why isn't the compiler doing eta expansion for the Dataset's filter operation?

Comment: Maybe because `filter` in Scala TraversableLike is not overloaded and in Spark Dataset there are many options

Comment: @T.Gawęda The same stands for `map`, but it works as expected for Datasets. That's why I added the example with map.

Comment: You are right!  So waiting for real answer :)

Comment: Wait, but map does have one additional implicit parameter, encoder

Comment: @T.Gawęda I see... the "Java" version for map has the encoder as a second parameter, so the compiler only finds one option for a single-parameter `map` and therefore it's able to do the conversion. However, for filter, it finds multiple candidates with a single parameter. I'll do some tests to verify if that's the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the nature of overloaded methods and ETA expansion. [Eta-expansion between methods and functions with overloaded methods in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala) explains why this fails.

The gist of it is the following (emphasis mine):

> when overloaded, applicability is undermined because **there is no
>   expected type (6.26.3, infamously)**. When not overloaded, 6.26.2
>   applies (eta expansion) because the type of the parameter determines
>   the expected type. When overloaded, the arg is **specifically typed with
>   no expected type**, hence 6.26.2 doesn't apply; therefore neither
>   overloaded variant of d is deemed to be applicable.

.....

> Candidates for overloading resolution are pre-screened by "shape". The
>   shape test encapsulates the intuition that eta-expansion is never used
>   because args are typed without an expected type. This example shows
>   that eta-expansion is not used even when it is "the only way for the
>   expression to type check."

As @DanielDePaula points out, the reason we don't see this effect in `DataSet.map` is because the overloaded method actually takes an additional `Encoder[U]` parameter:

```
def map[U : Encoder](func: T => U): Dataset[U] = withTypedPlan {
  MapElements[T, U](func, logicalPlan)
}

def map[U](func: MapFunction[T, U], encoder: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U] = {
  implicit val uEnc = encoder
  withTypedPlan(MapElements[T, U](func, logicalPlan))
}
```

Comment: The map function has similar interface for Java, but it works. Are you sure it depends on the Java interface?

Comment: Actually I've just found out that *any* overload makes the method lose the "expected type", so even if there was only `filter(expr: String)` and `filter(f: T => Boolean)` it wouldn't work. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala))

Comment: @DanieldePaula You're right, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala. I'll update the answer.

Comment: for map, the problem doesn't happen because there is not a "real" overload, since the alternative method has two parameters (the function and the encoder)

Comment: Yup, so it not depends on Java interface, but only on overloading :)

Comment: Definitely! I was wondering this myself lately when converting an application to Structured Streaming but I forgot to check.