# Simple issue - "Error: missing argument list for method"

Tags: scala

I have a simple class and a companion object with apply methods overloaded:

```
case class A(val s: String,
         val x: Int,
         val y: Int,
         val z: Int,
         val foo: Int => Int,
         val l: Option[List[String]])

object A {
    def apply(s: String, x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, foo: Int => Int) =
        new A(s, x, y, z, foo, None)

    def apply(s: String, x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, foo: Int => Int, l: List[String]) =
        new A(s, x, y, z, foo, Some(l))
}
```

Let's also define a function:

```
def foo(x: Int): Int = x + 1
```

Using the first constructor works:

```
scala> val a1 = A("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo)
a1: A = A(a1,1,2,3,$$Lambda$1842/2112068307@598e02f0,None)
```

However using the second does not:

```
val a2 = A("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo, List("b1", "b2"))
<console>:24: error: missing argument list for method foo
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `foo _` or `foo(_)` instead of `foo`.
       val a2 = A("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo, List("b1", "b2"))
```

The question(s): What is the reason I need to pass `foo _` or `foo(_)` instead of just foo as in the `a1` example? Also, can I redefine my class to make it possible to just use `foo`?

Comment: I wrap it up in `Some(l)` part in the body of the second `apply`.

Comment: Sorry I missed that and deleted my old comment when I realised

Comment: @toni057 I managed to dig out a question that describes the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala (you just have `apply`s instead of `r`s)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain this. My first thought was that it has something to do with type erasure, as [slouc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5599298/slouc) said, but then I looked at the signatures more closely, and neither of them have the same type signature even after the erasure:

Case class `apply`:

```
String, Int, Int, Int, Function1, Option
```

Companion object `apply` 1:

```
String, Int, Int, Int, Function1
```

Companion object `apply` 2:

```
String, Int, Int, Int, Function1, List
```

So, I don't see how that could be a case.

Trying to make it work I've noticed that it will work fine if you rename the second `apply` method to something else:

```
scala> val a1 = A("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo)
a1: A = A(a1,1,2,3,$$Lambda$1286/1904652802@6b649efa,None)

scala> val a2 = A.apply2("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo, List("b1", "b2"))
a2: A = A(a1,1,2,3,$$Lambda$1287/866073173@2dd63e3,Some(List(b1, b2)))
```

Or define both `apply` methods not in a companion object:

```
object B {

    def apply(s: String, x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, foo: Int => Int): A =
      new A(s, x, y, z, foo, None)

    def apply(s: String, x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, foo: Int => Int, l: List[String]): A =
      new A(s, x, y, z, foo, Some(l))
}
```

REPL:

```
scala> val a1 = B("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo)
a1: A = A(a1,1,2,3,$$Lambda$1351/814507488@50fa5938,None)

scala> val a2 = B("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo, List("b1", "b2"))
a2: A = A(a1,1,2,3,$$Lambda$1352/613231852@5d77be8e,Some(List(b1, b2)))
```

A third method, as [Robert Udah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473762/robert-udah) mentioned, defining `foo` as a function literal `(x: Int) => x + 1` also solves the issue.  However, it doesn't have to be `val`, could be `def`, as well:

```
def foo = (x: Int) => x + 1
```

Comment: It's very peculiar why defining an object B helps to what I intended to do in the first place. Any clue why it doesn't work as a companion object?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if `foo` is declared as a function `val`

```
scala> val foo = (x: Int) => x + 1
foo: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val a1 = A("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo)
a1: A = A(a1,1,2,3,<function1>,None)

scala> val a2 = A("a1", 1, 2, 3, foo, List("b1", "b2"))
a2: A = A(a1,1,2,3,<function1>,Some(List(b1, b2)))
```

Why `def foo` works fine for `a1` I'm not sure, but it might have something to do with `case class A` expecting a function instead of a method as these apparently are two different things in scala.

[Here is a post that might explain better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Comment: Just reading the post and it seems that it is the case that `A` expects a function instead of a method. Is there anyone who can corroborate more on this?