# Implicit method to function conversion doesn't work when passed as argument?

Tags: scala

I might be missing something but I came across a pattern that surprisingly doesn't work.
Here it is:

```
object A {
  def bar(func: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = 2
  def bar(func: Int => Int): Int = 3
  def foo(func: Int => Int): Int = 4
}

def f(n: Int) : Int = n + 1
val g: Int => Int = f

A.foo(f) // works fine
A.bar(f) // doesn't work
A.bar(g) // but this works
```

The compiler ask me to explicitly apply the method `f`in order to pass it (writing `f _`) :
`Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.`

I don't get why the conversion is implicitly made when passing `f` to `A.foo` but not when passed to `A.bar`. It might be related to the fact that `bar` has two overloads but I'm not sure why ?

I'm using scalac with Scala 2.12.8.

Comment: @francoisr gave a correct answer, but if you would like to also see some specification details about this issue, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala).

Comment: @slouc Thanks for the link. I added that to my answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message points you in the right direction: as a *method*, `f` is not directly equivalent to a value of type `Int => Int`, even though they are similar. In order to pass it as an argument, `f` needs to be converted to a value, which is often, but not always done implicitly.

When you declare `val g = f _`, or use `A.bar(f _)` you explicitly convert the method to a value.

Because the `bar` method is overloaded, the compiler is unsure which type you are converting `f` to (is it `Int => Int` or `(Int,Int) => Int`?). To avoid any surprise, it asks you for an explicit conversion. You can also make it compile using `A.bar(f: Int => Int)`, because that lifts the ambiguity by explicitly selecting one of the `bar` definitions.

The compiler might attempt to reason about this because you're passing a `Int => Int` and the implicit method->value lifting can only happen if you mean to give it to `bar(Int => Int)`, but in this case it just doesn't. There might be a technical reason for this, like the compiler not attempting to combine overloads resolutions and implicit lifting because of combinatorial explosion. I would consider it a minor limitation of the compiler, which is easily circumvented by being more explicit. More explicit is often better!

As linked in the comments by @slouc, more technical details on this issue are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala).