# Obtain reference to arity-0 scala function

Tags: scala, types, invocation

Scala allows functions with no parameter lists to be invoked without parentheses:

```
scala> def theAnswer() = 42
theAnswer: ()Int

scala> theAnswer
res5: Int = 42
```

How would I construct a scala expression that evaluates to the function `theAnswer` itself, rather than the result of `theAnswer`? Or in other words, how would I modify the expression `theAnswer`, so that the result was of type `() => Int`, and not type `Int`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with:

```
scala> theAnswer _
res0: () => Int = <function0>
```

From [the answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650989/when-do-i-have-to-treat-my-methods-as-partially-applied-functions-in-scala/6651099#6651099):

> The rule is actually simple: you have to write the _ whenever the
>   compiler is not explicitly expecting a Function object.

This call will create the new instance every time, because you're "converting" method to function (what is called "ETA expansion").

Comment: Does this create a new function object? E.g. if I do `val f: () => Int = theAnswer; f == f` I get true, however if I do `(theAnswer _) == (theAnswer _)` I get false. If I'm not mistaken this seems to indicate you're wrapping `theAnswer` into another function when you do `theAnswer _`

Comment: @Asad see the updated answer, of couse, you'll get false if you create the new instance.

Comment: I see. I'm looking for a way to get a reference to the actual function, not create another function that delegates to the first one. So I guess the answer to that question is, "the question is malformed, methods are not functions".

Comment: @Asad You're right and methods are not functions. In fact, the methods in Scala are Java methods, which cannot be referenced as variables, like functions do.

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
scala> val f = () => theAnswer
f: () => Int = <function0>

scala> val g = theAnswer _
g: () => Int = <function0>
```