# Scala: when exactly are function parameter types required?

Tags: scala

There are many ways functions can be defined in Scala, which leads to confusion about when exactly function parameter types are required. I usually start with the simplest possible definition and work my way down until compiler errors go away. I'd rather actually understand how this works.

For example:

```
_ + _

(x, y) => x + y

(x: Int, y: Int) => x + y

def sum(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y // as pointed out, this is a method,
                                // which not a function
```

Bonus points for a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well there are some corner cases like: a recursive method must be explicitly typed, but normally the rule of thumb is as follows: types have to come from somewhere.

Either they come from the reference part:

```
val function: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
```

or from the object part:

```
val function = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y
```

does not really matter. (in Scala!)

I know you question is about functions, but here is a similar example to illustrate Scala's type inference:

```
// no inference
val x: HashMap[String, Int] = new HashMap[String, Int]()
val x: HashMap[String, Int] = new HashMap[String, Int]

// object inference
val x: HashMap[String, Int] = new HashMap()
val x: HashMap[String, Int] = new HashMap
val x: HashMap[String, Int] = HashMap() // factory invocation

// reference inference
val x = new HashMap[String, Int]()
val x = new HashMap[String, Int]
val x = HashMap[String, Int]() // factory invocation

// full inference
val x = HashMap("dog" -> 3)
```

**EDIT** As requested I add the higher-order function case.

```
def higherOrderFunction(firstClassFunction: (Int, Int) => Int) = ...
```

can be called like this:

```
higherOrderFunction(_ + _) // the type of the firstClassFunction is omitted
```

But, this is not a special case. The type of the reference is explicitly mentioned. The following code illustrates a similar example.

```
var function: (Int, Int) => Int = null
function = _ + _
```

This is roughly equivalent to the higher-order function case.

Comment: There's a missing case which is very important for this question. If a method expects a function of a certain type, then you may omit the types in the when passing a function to that method.

Answer (score 5):

Your fourth example is a method, not a function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)). You must specify the types of arguments to a methods. The return type of a method can be inferred, unless the method is recursive, in which case it must be specified explicitly.

Comment: A concise list of the practical differences between methods and functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926047/debunking-scala-myths/4812176#4812176